# Irwin Hall distribution with varying n

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose I have the following problem, I want to add a random uniform number from $[0,1]$ every time in a variable. If n is the number of times I added, then:

$$
X(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} U_i
$$

Where $U_i$ are uniform random variables from $[0,1]$.

I want to for each n the probability of $X$ exceeding $0.3$ at **exactly** that n.

In other words, I want to find the following probability:

$$
P(X(n)>0.3 | X(n-1)<0.3)
$$

I now $X(n)$ is an Irwin-Hall distribution but I 'm struggling because $X(n)$ **depends** on $X(n-1)$ and so it is incorrect to say that:

$$
P(X(n)>0.3 | X(n-1)<0.3) = P(X(n)>0.3)*P(X(n-1)<0.3)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of $X(1)$ first being greater than $z$ (with $0<z<1$) will be $1-z$. That, of course, you already know.

So we need to find the probability that $X(n)$ is the first time that sum is greater than $z$.  The probability that $X(n-1)<z$ and $X(n)>z$ requires integrating over the product of the pdf of the Irwin-Hall distribution for $n-1$ and the probability that the $n$-th observation kicks the sum over $z$.

For $n>0$ and $0<z<1$, the pdf of the Irwin-Hall distribution is

$${z^{n-1}}\over{(n-1)!}$$

So the integral of interest is

$$\int_0^z {{x^{n-2}}\over{(n-2)!}}(1-(z-x))=\frac{(n-z) z^{n-1}}{n!}$$

For $n=1$ and $z=0.3$ this results in 0.7.  For $n=2$ and $z=0.3$ this results in 0.255.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggling with it all day long