# Drawing from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose I have an unlimited number of draws from a uniform distribution [0,1]. I want to keep on drawing until the sum of all my a values >=x (where 0<x<1).

I want to find the probability that my score ends between x and 1 when trying to do this and when it does, the expected value of my score.

Obviously the percentage chance of 'busting' is just 1 - the chance that my score is between x and 1. Intuitively, I'm tempted to say that when my score is between x and 1, on average it is halfway between x and 1, but I'm not 100% positive on that.

I looked at some other forums and found some things that seemed like they were kind of similar, but I wasn't quite sure where to take it from there.

I looked at this: [Irwin Hall distribution with varying n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682215/irwin-hall-distribution-with-varying-n)

right now this is where I'm at, I sum up from n=1 to n=inf
$$\frac{(n-z) z^{n-1}}{n!}$$

but for each n here I need to subtract the probability that the sum made it to over 1 for that n and I need to figure out how to find out that out...

for n draws out of a uniform distribution, I believe the probability that the sum is less than 1 is 1/n! but I can't just multiply what I have by 1/n! for each sum in the series because that would be 'overcounting' some of the area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(t)$ be the probability that you succeed starting from a sum of $t$; so you want $f(0)$. A one-step analysis yields

$$
f(t)=1-x+\int_t^xf(u)\mathrm du\;.
$$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ yields

$$
f'(t)=-f(t)\;,
$$

and thus $f(t)=c\mathrm e^{-t}$. Since $f(x)=1-x$, we must have $c\mathrm e^{-x}=1-x$, thus $c=\mathrm e^x(1-x)$, thus $f(t)=\mathrm e^{x-t}(1-x)$ and thus

$$
f(0)=\mathrm e^x(1-x)\;.
$$

You’re right that your expected score conditional on success is $\frac{1+x}2$, since the score is uniformly distributed over $[x,1]$, no matter from where you reach it.

Comment: How is $f(x) = 1-x$? If we start from $x$, the probability of attaining a sum in $[x,1]$ should be $1$, I believe.

Comment: @J.333: No – if we start from $x$, the next result is uniformly distributed over $[x,1+x]$; in that interval of length $1$, the interval $[x,1]$ of length $1-x$ occupies a fraction $1-x$ and leads to success; the rest of the interval leads to failure.

Comment: But why would one keep drawing if the result is already in the interval [x,1]?

Comment: @J.333: One of us seems to have misunderstood the question. You draw from a uniform distribution $[0,1]$, and you sum all the values. You don't have to keep drawing to end up in $[1,x+1]$. All you have to do in order to fail when you're at $x$ is to draw a single value larger than $1-x$.

Comment: But if you are at $x$, why would you keep drawing? I take it that you are drawing until you reach the interval $[x,1]$

Comment: @J.333: I'm sorry, I don't know I can explain it more clearly than in the previous message. You don't keep drawing. You draw a single number from $[0,1]$, you add it to your previous sum (in this case $x$), and that can take you beyond $1$. You don't have to keep drawing to end up beyond $1$. The step from $x$ to beyond $1$ is taken in a single, indivisible step, with no option anywhere in between where you might stop drawing. Perhaps read the question again carefully.